# mysql select greatest value from multiple sum

Tags: mysql, sum, max

I am using the following results table

```
Results Table
__________________________________________
player_a| player_b | player_c |   year 
________|________  |__________|___________|
100      150        150        2015  
100      -50        -50        2015 
100      350        250        2014
200      350        250        2014
```

What i would like to do is get the sum for each player per year.
Using the following Select i get the desired results.

```
SELECT (

SELECT SUM( player_a )
FROM `results`
WHERE year =2015
) AS player_a_2015, (

SELECT SUM( player_a)
FROM `results`
WHERE year =2014
) AS player_a_2014
```

How can i get the maximum sum result only ?

ie For player_a should be 300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(player_a) AS spa
FROM results
GROUP BY year
ORDER BY spa DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: thank you very much, that's exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

Make sure you wrap your OR condition in parenthesis so it evaluates them both.

```
SELECT SUM(player_a) AS sum_score
  FROM results
 WHERE (year = '2015' OR year = '2014')
```

**EDIT**

If you're wanting the maximum score by year, and then to sum that - this should be OK.

```
SELECT MAX(max_sum_score) AS max_sum_score
  FROM ( SELECT year
              , SUM(player_a) AS max_sum_score
           FROM results
          WHERE (year = '2015' OR year = '2014')
          GROUP BY year 
       ) a
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Actually, looking at it - how would it come to 300? The answer I posted would get you 500 - are you wanting the Maximum score for each year?

Comment: maybe i didnt explain it correctly. i would like to get the highest value, from the 2 sums, not the sum of those 2

Comment: Just setting up a table in MySQL to test that SQL for you... 1 sec

Comment: Yep - the edited SQL returns 300 in the table I have setup to test.

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna use,

```
SELECT MAX(SUM_A),YEAR FROM (
    SELECT SUM( player_a ) as SUM_A, YEAR
    FROM results
GROUP BY YEAR
) A_SCORE;
```

This will do it in one go(obviously for one player).